# how can i access properties defined dynamically inside php class

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop

trying to develop a class associated with table(like in frameworks).
assume we have a class named Book

```
class Book
{  
  public function save()
  {
     ....
  }

 }

$book = new book;
$book->id = '1';
$book->name = 'some';
$book->save();
```

the problem is how can i access this dynamically created properties inside save() to save new record

Comment: Do you have any predefined properties within the class?

Comment: no i don't. @SahilGulati. active record class has only CRUD methods

Comment: For that you can try either of the answers posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it that way (note that there are other solutions to this problem) :

```
public function save() {
    $properties = get_object_vars($this);
    print_r($properties);
    // do something with it.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find properties in an object with:

```
$properties = get_object_vars($book);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Answer (score 1):

here is complete code that you should use:

```html
<?php 

class Book
{  
  public function save()
  {
     $vars = get_object_vars($this);
     var_dump($vars);
  }

 }

$book = new book;
$book->id = '1';
$book->name = 'some';
$book->save();

?>
```